# How to respond to a second question asked in comments to your answer?

Tags: discussion

To start off, the comment in question is here - [Compile Error: Incompatible value type](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8025/compile-error-incompatible-value-type/8027#comment11365_8027)

Essentially, I answered the original question, and then the user had more troubles after my response. Should I request this user post a second question as this new question is technically different than the original one? Should I edit his original post to include his second question and then edit my answer to include the answer to his second question? How would you handle this and what is the proper approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the followup question can be framed as a second, stand-alone question, then please direct the author to do so. If the comment was simply asking for clarification or was very closely related to the current question/answer, you could edit the post in place to expand the current information.

One thing you want to avoid is answering follow-up questions in an on-going conversation in comments. That essential *breaks* [the purpose of having a Stack Exchange site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/about). If the question (or followups) absolutely *need* that type of back-and-forth collaboration, it probably was not a good fit for this site.